# How to add a new method to ProductsController in spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I want to add a method called quick_view, which is basically a show method but much simpler and meant to be served with Ajax on hover on a product.

How can i achieve this ? How can i open the ProductsController of spree and add before_filters and also specify the appropriate routes..

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Doco for that is at https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/logic.html

Create a class called `app/controllers/products_controller_decorator.rb`, and put something like this in it:

```
Spree::ProductsController.class_eval do

  before_filter :my_filter, :only => :quick_view

  def quick_view
    # your code goes here
  end

  private
    def my_filter
      # code for your before filter goes here
    end

end
```

As for the routes, you'll be able to add it in your `routes.rb` file just like any other route, but you'll need to specify that it's a spree route:

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.draw do
  # Your route goes inside this block
end
```

Comment: Thanks man for the answer! And ended up copying the whole controller to my application ( which solved my problem ), but your solution is much better...

Comment: Glad to help. And yes, avoid copying the whole controller at all costs - this is a nightmare when you have to update spree.

If the answer was correct, consider upvoting it, or marking it as correct. It lets others know that was the right answer, and also gives me some points ;)